# lists:append with list comprehensions

Tags: list, erlang, list-comprehension

How can I define `lists:append` function with list comprehension?

I want something like

```
1> append([[1, 2, 3], [a, b], [4, 5, 6]]).
[1,2,3,a,b,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that you can use elements from a generator in a later generator in the same list comprehension!

```
1> Lists = [[1, 2, 3], [a, b], [4, 5, 6]].
[[1,2,3],[a,b],[4,5,6]]
2> [N || L <- Lists, N <- L].             
[1,2,3,a,b,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[Y || X <- [[1,2,3],[a,b],[4,5,6]], Y <- X ].
```